# Using pytest from a BAT file

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, pytest

I am trying to using pytest from a BAT file. I have tried something like this

```
..\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pytest -v src/datasets_test.py::TestDatasetsOperations::test_dataset_add
```

But it seems to do nothing. How can I make it work?

EDIT: the question is similar, but no one will go to other question if he thinks the error is with pytest

Comment: If you look at the linked question, you'll notice that this question and that question both have the same answer of "use `call` to run a script from inside of a script." The title is misleading, but the information itself is still relevant.

Comment: I have removed your latest edit, please read the comment above, to find out why.

Comment: No one will go to other question, if  he thinks the problem is with pytest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call another script from a batch script, you need to use `call`.

```
call ..\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pytest -v src/datasets_test.py::TestDatasetsOperations::test_dataset_add
```